Run save immediately JpaRepository in Spring Batch
hello my problem is the following, I am doing the saving of an object, this object has a not null field with null value so when doing the save it should give error.
that exception is caught by a catch and one of the actions performed inside the catch is the deletion of the object.
main clas
try {
            
   idHist = gestorBBDDPrimario.updateBbdd(dispositivoMovil);
            /** more code **/
} catch (RuntimeException | IOException | EIACException e) {
    log.info("catch", e);
    gestorBBDDPrimario.deleteBbdd(dispositivoMovil);
    
}

updatebbdd (save)
public Long updateBbdd(DispositivoMovil dispositivoMovil) {

        DispositivoMovilHist registroHist = null;

        if (dispositivoMovil != null) {
            Optional<DispositivoMovil> registro = dispositivoMovilRepository.findById(dispositivoMovil.getId());
            // Crea el registro a guardar en históricos
            if (registro.isPresent()) {
                /** mode code **/
            }else{
            dispositivoMovilRepository.save(dispositivoMovil);
        }

        return registroHist;
    }

delete
public DispositivoMovil deleteBbdd(DispositivoMovil dispositivoMovil) {

        if (dispositivoMovil != null) {
            Optional<DispositivoMovil> registro = dispositivoMovilRepository.findById(dispositivoMovil.getId());
            if (registro.isPresent()) {
                dispositivoMovilRepository.deleteById(dispositivoMovil.getId());
            }
        }
        
        return dispositivoMovil;
    }

As this code stands, the following would happen:
the method continued executing and for another different reason it entered the catch, at that point in the findbyId before the deleteByID it returned an object but that object does not exist in the database because it did not meet the condition of a null attribute. and a few lines later it executes the save and throws the exception but already past that catch
[WARN ] 2024-05-02 21:23:18.472 [main] SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000 
[ERROR] 2024-05-02 21:23:18.472 [main] SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: no se puede realizar una inserción NULL en ("ORND1B"."DISPOSITIVO_MOVIL"."MARCA")

if on the other hand I add .flush() after the save, this time it enters in the catch because of the exception:
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

and in the console displays:
[WARN ] 2024-05-02 21:27:38.990 [main]  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000 
[ERROR] 2024-05-02 21:27:38.990 [main]  SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: no se puede realizar una inserción NULL en ("ORND1B"."DISPOSITIVO_MOVIL"."MARCA")
[INFO ] 2024-05-02 21:27:38.993 [main]  AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements 

but if I continue debugging the "catch" log does not appear, and once it enters the deleteBbdd, the findById still returns an object, despite having launched the save exception and if you continue the execution a few lines later the "catch" log and the exception stack appear.
My question is, is there any way that the save is executed in the line where it is called and this exception is caught only and only the catch and in such a way that the findbyId returns an empty object?
I tried with @transactional, with flush before findbyid and nothing.
when the exception is thrown outside the catch, it leads to a problem already registered in spring batch https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826
